# Dynamically Add/Remove select box HTML table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp, select

Hi could anyone please help me out how to generate the select boxes dynamically using java script.The option values are come from database.

```
  <th> <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Department<span style="color: red">*</span></label></th>
                                    <td><html:select property="deparment" value="" onblur="dropDown(this);"> 
                                            <html:option value="">Select</html:option>
                                        </html:select>
                                        <html:errors property="deparment"/>
                                        <p id="deparment" style="color:red"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <th> <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Reporting To<span style="color: red">*</span></label></th>
                                    <td>
                                        <html:select property="reportingto" value="" onblur="dropDown(this);"> 
                                            <html:option value="">Select</html:option>
                                        </html:select>
                                        <html:errors property="reportingto"/>
                                        <p id="reportingto" style="color:red"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <a onclick="adddepartment();" href="javascript:;" style="font-size:12px;">Add New</a>
                                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to send an Ajax request to a Servlet, which will then read the database and respond, and the javascript will add the response to the HTML DOM.